# Unicode character Rocket not shown in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, xfce, unicode, special-characters

On my Lubuntu 16.04 installation, I cannot see some Unicode characters,  for example the [Rocket character `U+1F680`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f680/index.htm) in Firefox.

Are there any extra packages, I have to install to be able to see those chars? What are the family of those charaters?

I also installed `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` but still those characters are missing:

,

while others work fine like:

☆

This problem only exists on my Lubuntu installation, which I started with Lubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet, and upgraded to 16.04 yesterday. On Ubuntu 16.04 all characters work fine in Firefox 48

Comment: FWIW, I can see it on my Firefox 48 on Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the site that you have linked to:

> ***You need a font that supports this character to even have a hope of
>   seeing it correctly in the browser.***

You'll need to ensure that the `fonts-symbola` package is installed to be able to see such glyphs.

Comment: great! this worked: `sudo apt-get install fonts-symbola` and then restart firefox ;)

Comment: @rubo77 Interesting, I am guessing `fonts-symbola` are not installed by default on Xubuntu? Good to know.

Comment: I checked again: it is Lubuntu with xfce4 and not Xubuntu, I started this installation a year ago with Lubuntu 15.04